# Mount WebDAV as drive in Windows 8

Tags: webdav, windows-8

I'm trying to mount a WebDAV share as a drive on Windows 8. I've tried setting up WebDAV server on both Windows 2012 and Debian Linux, but both yield the same error when attempting to mount from client.

I have verified that the Linux WebDAV works through [cadaver](http://www.webdav.org/cadaver/)-command, it authenticates successfully with the credentials given and I am able to download files. I can also use a browser to access it successfully from client using these credentials. So WebDAV server seems to work.

Windows 8 client however gives me this error:

```
C:\>net use * http://10.0.0.5/webdav/
System error 67 has occurred.

The network name cannot be found.
```

I get the same error if I try to mount using Windows Explorer. "/webdav/" is the subdirectory I have configured for WebDAV access on the server.

There is no firewall blocking access to server. As I mentioned I am able to connect using browser, so network is not the issue.

Are there any additional steps required to get this working and/or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:**
Logs from Apache says the following (hostnames has been changed to protect the innocent):

```
==> /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log <==
debian1.my.net:80 10.0.0.4 - - [13/Jul/2013:17:53:00 +0200] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 200 229 "-" "DavClnt"
debian1.my.net:80 10.0.0.4 - - [13/Jul/2013:17:53:03 +0200] "OPTIONS /WebDAV HTTP/1.1" 200 193 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.2.9200"
debian1.my.net:80 10.0.0.4 - - [13/Jul/2013:17:53:03 +0200] "PROPFIND /WebDAV HTTP/1.1" 405 584 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.2.9200"
```

I'm also able to access WebDAV using .Net and [SharpBox](http://sharpbox.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Found the Solution](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/windows-7-webdav-web-folders-support-for-64bit/a48a13a3-b9c4-4d4f-a3cd-47ce9e52d7a9): Basic auth.

Change `BasicAuthLevel` to 2 under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters`

Then restart WebClient service:

```
net stop WebClient
net start WebClient
```

My Apache2 config for those interested:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/webdav/mounts
        <Directory /var/www/webdav/mounts>
                Options Indexes MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        Alias /webdav /var/www/webdav/mounts

        <Location /webdav>
           DAV On
           AuthType Basic
           AuthName "webdav"
           AuthUserFile /var/www/webdav/passwd.dav
           Require valid-user
       </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

**Edit:** Ended up configuring WebDAV to use Digest so it works without modifying registry on Windows client. Posted result [here](http://blog.tedd.no/2013/07/13/apache-webdav-setup-compatible-with-windows/) in case anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is running linux it is possible that the path might be case-sensitive.

This error can also be caused by bad credentials; try specifying the `/user` option.

Comment: Good catch, but sadly that was just a typo in my question. I was using correct casing when accessing. Posted Apache log entries as well, from the logs we see it actually uses "WebDAV" instead of "webdav" as my Alias (Apache config) says - so something magical is happening here. :)